# Changing font style in PHP link

Tags: php, html, css, fonts

Though I have spent some time on this, I have not been able to find the solution though.
I am asked to show a "go back" message after clicking that. This message has to be written with the same font the person click on. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example - Changing the font</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['fontStyle'])){
            $font=$_GET['fontStyle'];
            unset($_GET); 
            echo "<a href='Example01.php'>";
            echo "<font face=$font>Go back</font>";
            echo "</a>";
        } else{
            echo "<h1>Choose a font style</h1>";
            echo "<a href='Example01.php?fontStyle=verdana'>verdana</a><br />";
            echo "<a href='Example01.php?fontStyle=arial'>arial</a><br />";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you missed to address your problem, but I can see what's the problem here. You should use CSS instead of old `font` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
echo "<font face=$font>Go back</font>";
```

to

```
echo "<span style='font-family:".$font.";'>Go back</span>";
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<font>` tag is no [longer supported](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp). Use `style` attribute with `font-family` property :

```
    if (isset($_GET['fontStyle'])){
        $font=$_GET['fontStyle'];
        // unset($_GET); // unset $_GET array is not necessary
        echo '<a href="Example01.php" style="font-family:'.$font.';">Go back</a>';
    } else{
        echo "<h1>Choose a font style</h1>";
        echo "<a href='Example01.php?fontStyle=verdana'>verdana</a><br />";
        echo "<a href='Example01.php?fontStyle=arial'>arial</a><br />";
    }
```